# AWS Amplify Storage.get() - AWSAccessKeyId is undefined

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I'm struggling with a react native project utilizing AWS amplify, both Auth and Storage.

Calling `Storage` from this service file in my project:

```
import Amplify, {Auth, Storage} from 'aws-amplify'
import config from './config'

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: config.Auth,
  Storage: config.Storage,
})

export {
  Auth,
  Storage,
}
```

config is:

```
AWS: {
  Auth: {
    region: 'us-east-X',
    userPoolId: 'us-east-XXXXXXX',
    userPoolWebClientId: 'XXXXXXXXX',
    identityPoolId: 'us-east-X:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  },
  Storage: {
    AWSS3: {
      bucket: 'XXXXXXX',
      region: 'us-east-X',
    },
  },
},
```

By this point, the user has authenticated with Auth. Calling:

```
Storage.get('public/fileName.gif', { expires: 120 })
```

Results in a signed URL that appears to be missing the access key, which it should be generating from the IAM logged in user.

Here's an example signed URL it generates:

```
https://expyhealth-stg.s3.amazonaws.com/public/activityImages/Ankle%20Pumps.gif?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=undefined%2F20201020%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201020T204616Z&X-Amz-Expires=120&X-Amz-Signature=f40bad142a9b190f9d9959bb9db0ad077c0cecab5171098f033a700cb9aa45b5&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&x-amz-user-agent=aws-sdk-js-v3-react-native-%40aws-sdk%2Fclient-s3%2F1.0.0-gamma.8%20aws-amplify%2F3.6.0%20react-native&x-id=GetObject"
```

Notice the `X-Amz-Credential=undefined`

I've been following the thread here for hours and keep coming up short. I cannot determine why it isn't generating the access key.

Using `aws-amplify` version `3.3.4`

Here is the bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1599854584652",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1599854581275",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/Cognito_ExpyHealthStagingAuth_Role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::XXXXXXXX",
                "arn:aws:s3:::XXXXXXXX/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please mask the account id, user pool id and any other sensitive information. Thanks

Comment: I suppose I didn't view these as sensitive, given they are not secret keys, but sure I can mask

Answer (score 0):

I solve a similar issue by editing the *IAM trust relationship* as follows:

- Open the AWS console
- Go to IAM
- Go to roles
- Select the role specified as the `Authenticated role` of your identity pool
- Open "Trust Relationship" tab
- Click "Edit trust relationship"
- Paste the following:

  ```
   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
       {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
             "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
         },
         "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
         "Condition": {
             "StringEquals": {
                 "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "eu-west-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
             },
             "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                 "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
             }
           }
         }
       ]
     }
  ```

*Tip: compare your configuration with the one generated by the AWS Amplify CLI.*

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I already have that exact policy :/